# Pass a route segment as callback argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building my first app in express. Is it possible to somehow pass a route segment as an argument to a callback?

```
app.get('/connect/:mySegment', myCallback(mySegment));
```

Specifically, I'm using passport with several strategies for authentication. So rather than doing,

```
app.get('/connect/twitter',
  passport.authorize('twitter')
);
app.get('/connect/facebook',
  passport.authorize('facebook')
);
```

I would like to do something along the lines of...

```
app.get('/connect/:service', passport.authorize(service));
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can do

```
app.get('/connect/:mySegment', function(req, res){
    // then you can use req.params.mySegment
});
```